# iReport 2.0.4 Connection - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I try to get iReport 2.0.4 connected to my database resulting in a ClassNotFound exception. 
So I downloaded the MS JDBC drivers 4.1 and 4.0 for SQL server. (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774)

I added the jdb jar file to the iReport Classpath:

[image]

I restarted iReport and tried to connect to the db again:

File > Report Wizard > Database JDBC connection > Next >

JDBC Driver (com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver) 
JDBC URL: jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://(myIP):1433;DatabaseName=MYDATABASE

I am getting the same exception.

[image]

Could anyone please point me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The class name is `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` (notice the order of elements: `sqlserver` **before** `jdbc`).

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel - That was it is. I just selected the value (com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver") from the iReport dropdown without even noticing the issue t you pointed out. Thanks!

Comment: I believe there has been an old JDBC driver with that classname. BTW: iReport 2 is pretty old (the last version is 5.6, and it has been replaced by JasperSoft Studio).

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel - Mark, please post your comment(s) as the answer below (when you have a chance) so that I can select it  as the official answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the classname of the JDBC driver is incorrect. The correct classname is `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` (notice the order of elements: `sqlserver` **before** `jdbc`).

I believe that one of the first Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver did have the classname you tried, but it has since been replaced.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are added `sqljdbc4.jar` in your class path .
--> Tools->Options->Classpath tab :

[image]

1 - In **JDBC Driver** : `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`

2 - In **JDBC URL** : `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433` without database name only port

3 - Database username and password in **credentials** section

[image]